# Unexpected low performance of N-channel MOSFET when powered with 3.3 V (RPi)

Tags: mosfet, raspberry-pi

I have the following circuit to power DC motors at 5 V using a RPi 4. The MOSFET is a RFP30N06LE (https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/RFP30N06LE.pdf), 1n4001 diode, 10k resistor.

[image]

When applying 3.3 V at the gate, I am seeing extremely little current flowing. I would expect 3.3 V to easily allow lots of current to flow based on:

[image]

When using a http://www.unisonic.com.tw/datasheet/30N06.pdf that has a higher Vgs(th) of 2-4 V, I see much more current flow, and the motor spins up (somewhat slowly) by itself.

I am confused as to why I am getting such little current flowing through the motor, I have to use my hand to help it start turning over. As well as why the FET with the higher threshold would allow more current to flow. I also tried with 3 units and observed the same results.

Comment: How much current the motor draws at 5V? Can the supply provide it? Is the FET correctly connected to the circuit? Pinout correct?

Comment: All source voltages must be zero because the source is connected to 0 volts. Are you sure you are measuring it correctly and using a voltage range and not a current range?

Comment: Where did you get the RFP30N06LE from? Can you show us a photo of it? What do you mean by 'voltage at the source'?

Comment: > How much current the motor draws at 5V? Can the supply provide it? Is the FET correctly connected to the circuit? Pinout correct?

--- around 1A, PSU is 4A so plenty to work with. FET is correctly connected and pinout correct, verified with TONS of probing with multimeter.

Comment: Your schematic shows your source is grounded...why are you measuring a voltage there?

Comment: > All source voltages must be zero because the source is connected to 0 volts. Are you sure you are measuring it correctly and using a voltage range and not a current range? --- definitely using a voltage range to control the FET, measuring the voltage at the Gate and at the Drain I can see the expected values of 3.3v and 5v respectively

Comment: > Where did you get the RFP30N06LE from? Can you show us a photo of it? What do you mean by 'voltage at the source'? --- Amazon, not in an anti-static package. I've just ordered a batch from sparkfun to check that it's not a counterfeit (although they were many 4&5 star reviews).

Comment: > Your schematic shows your source is grounded...why are you measuring a voltage there? --- I've tried putting the FET before and after the motor. Just cleaned up the question to talk about the shown schematic case only.

Comment: I would recommend using 5V for Vgs.  For an application like this, you really want to drive the FET into saturation.

Comment: Just to be sure:  The grounds of both supplies are tied together?

Comment: > Just to be sure: The grounds of both supplies are tied together? --- yep!

Comment: > I would recommend using 5V for Vgs. For an application like this, you really want to drive the FET into saturation. --- RPi is 3.3v logic, and with a 2v max Vgs(th) I would expect it to be fully on at 3.3v

Comment: The Vgs threshold specifies the voltage at which the current reaches 250uA.  It will be in the linear region for a ways above this threshold.  Can you measure the voltage at the drain of the FET when the circuit is energized?

Comment: > (Is the source indeed at GND/0 V? You didn't place a current sense resistor there, did you?) indeed 0, directly tied to the RPi GND pin

Comment: > The Vgs threshold specifies the voltage at which the current reaches 250uA. It will be in the linear region for a ways above this threshold. Can you measure the voltage at the drain of the FET when the circuit is energized? --- 3.47v and the motor takes a while to reach there (starts higher and slowly comes down as the motor spins up).

Comment: I suggest waiting until you get your parts from Sparkfun and then try again.  Something doesn't seem quite right...

Comment: If the circuit you've drawn accurately represents what you built, then I can't think what would be the problem here, other than bad transistors. Those are the two options, you haven't built what you think you've built, or those FETs are bad.

Comment: OK, I would expect to see a lower voltage at the drain.  Something close to 0V.  The behavior indicates (to me) that the FET is just slightly forward biased.  Is it possible the FETs you are using are not the ones stated?

Comment: > OK, I would expect to see a lower voltage at the drain. Something close to 0V. The behavior indicates (to me) that the FET is just slightly forward biased. Is it possible the FETs you are using are not the ones stated? ---- I according to the packaging, yes. I should be getting the sparkfun ones soon so there should be no doubt then.

Comment: Update: new mosfets behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It is doing what I would expect. You are at the threshold voltage of that MOSFET, it starts to enhance but will not be fully enhanced until the Vgs reaches at least 5 volts (the graph is very granular). All measurements for Vgs should be taken at the gate and source leads, any wire etc in between such as additional wire in the source can have a voltage drop giving you an invalid reading.

There are other MOSFETs that will work. It is possible you have a substitute MOSFET that has slightly different characteristics labeled as the original part.

Answer (score 0):

This image shows that the 3.3V VGS may not be clearing the miller region, so the drain voltage may not be zero. As other have said, you need more gate voltage.

[image]

Also the silicon diode should be replaced with a Schottky diode. The reverse recovery current of the 1N4007 goes straight to the gate through the miller capacitance, slowing turn-off thus increasing heat.

Edit: The above diagram is a bit misleading. At least it shows the gate charge with the miller plateau. The VDS graph shows VDS decreasing as soon as VGSth occurs. In fact when driving an inductive load with a flyback diode, VDS does not start decreasing until the current through the diode is zero at the start of the miller plateau. ID is maximum. There is significant power dissipation in this region. During the miller plateau. VDS drops to zero. Notice that VGS does not change significantly. This is due to all the input current is being used to charge the miller capacitor CGD. For a fast turn- on, there must be significant gate current. The RPi will not be able to support the required current an it’s output voltage will be less than 3.3 during switching.

Most often a gate drive circuit is required between MCU and MOSFET when using PWM.

Comment: This makes sense, also will look into the other diode!